# How can i count rows in my created mysql

Tags: php, mysql

How can i count rows in my created mysql.

This is my statement

```
(
"SELECT COUNT(ct.title)
FROM exp_channel_titles as ct
LEFT JOIN exp_channel_data as cd on (ct.entry_id = cd.entry_id)
where ct.channel_id=1
and ct.status= 'open'
Group by ct.entry_id
");
```

When i print_r this statement, it gives me this output:

```
CI_DB_mysql_result Object ( [conn_id] => Resource id #9 [result_id] => Resource id #173 [result_array] => Array ( ) [result_object] => Array ( ) [current_row] => 0 [num_rows] => 135 [row_data] => )
```

But i only want the number 135 out

This is how i tried, but i does not work and i dont understand why?

```
$result = mysql_query($resultsofRestaurants);
$count = mysql_fetch_array($result);
print_r($count);
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: what do you get when running the query in phpMyAdmin or your other sql client?

Comment: Just updated my question :D

Comment: This cannot be real code. The legacy deprecated extension doesn't generate objects of class `CI_DB_mysql_result`. Are you using CodeIgniter or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing right now is you are counting `ct.entry_id` which will give you atleast 1 value on each row.

You need to count `cd.entry_id` instead of `ct.entry_id`.

```
SELECT  COUNT(cd.entry_id)
FROM    exp_channel_titles as ct
        LEFT JOIN exp_channel_data as cd 
           ON ct.entry_id = cd.entry_id
WHERE   ct.channel_id=1 AND
        ct.status= 'open'
GROUP   BY ct.entry_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `mysql_num_rows($result)`

Answer (score 0):

This will 100% work

```
$rows= mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("YOUR SQL QUERY"));
```